# Is there a way to return only the field value from a mongodb.find query projection?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a code snippet which looks like this

```
MongoDatabase db = DbConnection.getDbConnection(); //the connection to the database is successfully made
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("students"); //access the collection called students
FindIterable<Document> findIterable =  collection.find()
               .projection(fields(include("studentId"), excludeId()));

for(Document document:findIterable){
            System.out.println(document.toJson());
        }
```

The output I get is

```
{"studentId": 1}
{"studentId": 2}
{"studentId": 3}
```

However I want to get the output only with the field value; i.e not as a JSON object, so that it would look something like this

```
1
2
3
```

Is there any way that I could do to get the output like this?

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(document.toJson().studentId);